# How to create a loop that makes a new input over and over again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a for loop that keeps asking for a new input that has a different name each time so it would be `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, etc. That way I don't have to keep making more inputs or a specified amount of them.

I also need it to print the same question on each input.

> "What would you like to add to your soup?"

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: Use a dictionary for the names.

Comment: Is your question regarding the structure of such a for loop in python or are you asking about how to store an indeterminate number of answers?

Comment: I want to store an indeterminate number of answers, but it needs to be a seperate question for each one. @CorbinMc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store an indeterminate number of responses to your questions, you should use a list. Create an empty list before beginning your for loop and use the `list.append()` function to add each answer to your list as you go.

A list has the advantage of being relatively memory efficient. Using a dictionary requires you to save key-value pairs (using twice as much memory) instead of simply relying on the order of values in memory.

Sample code might look like this:

```
n = 10 # the number of iterations to perform
answers = list()
for i in range(0, n):
     answers.append(input("question?"))

print(answers[2]) #this would print the third entered answer
print(answers[4]) #this would print the fourth entered answer
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy, but you probably don't need a `for` loop.  Here is a simple example using a dictionary:

```
answers = {}
count = 1

while True:
    ans = input("What would you like to add to your soup? ")
    if ans.lower() == 'nothing':
        break

    answers['q' + str(count)] = ans
    count += 1

print(answers)
```

We have an infinite loop (`while True`) but a break-out when the user enters "Nothing".  You don't HAVE to have this, but in most applications you will need something like that.

Sample run:

```
What would you like to add to your soup? carrots
What would you like to add to your soup? peas
What would you like to add to your soup? chicken
What would you like to add to your soup? noodles
What would you like to add to your soup? nothing
{'q4': 'noodles', 'q2': 'peas', 'q1': 'carrots', 'q3': 'chicken'}
```

Using a dictionary you can use whatever names you like, but I wonder if you really need those names, and why you need them.  Normally it would be enough just to append the answers onto a list.

```
answers = []

while True:
    ans = input("What would you like to add to your soup? ")
    if ans.lower() == 'nothing':
        break

    answers.append(ans)

print(answers)
```

As you can see, the code is much simpler, and simple is good.  The output from the example would be:

```
['carrots', 'peas', 'chicken', 'noodles']
```

Comment: Well, I'm using it for a program I have to write at school in which I need to get the answers and put them into a .csv and print on a separate line along with 2 more rows of information next to it. Like artist name - how long they're on stage - how  much they get payed.

Comment: I also don't have a clue about much of the stuff going on in this dictionary.

Comment: You probably want the list solution then, Keep It Simple (KISS).

Answer (score 1):

A variation on a theme using a list:

```
answers = []
while True:
    whom = raw_input("Who is on stage ")
    if whom == "":
        break
    duration = raw_input("For how many minutes ")
    answers.append((whom,duration))
for i in answers:
    print i[0], "was on stage for", i[1], "minutes"
```